# T-SQL crazy function result

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql

I have this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckAkvNames (@Name VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @NoTexist int = 1

     SELECT 
         @NoTexist = CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
     FROM 
         [dbo].[Names] 
     WHERE 
         [Name] = @Name  

     RETURN @NoTexist
END 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Names] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT chkNames CHECK(dbo.CheckAkvNames([Name]) = 1);
GO
```

The problem is, when I run this on empty table I can't insert ...

So this change works:

```
CASE WHEN (COUNT(*) - 1) > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

WHY? Any ideas?

Edit:
Aim is to insert only names that are not in the table. I know it would be better to use key, point of the question is not to find better solution but why this solution does not work.

Comment: Can you explain what this logic is supposed to be doing?  It seems strange that you want to insert names into one table that are not in another.  I would want all names in a single table, perhaps with a flag to define their role or origin.  Also, you have two tables in the query, but have not specified which -- or both -- are empty.

Comment: Fixed the question...Theres only one table, funcion and constraint should make sure that Name is unique, but it cant be a key. The confusion (two table names) happened becouse i renamed the table for the question from my language to english and forgot to rename it in the constraint part.

Comment: What do you try to accomplish with this check constraint?

Comment: It seems like you want to only insert if the name does not exist already.  If so just make a non-duplicate key index -- it will work much faster `O(1)`! and use less code and not use triggers.... just better all around.

Comment: I know that... The point of the question is not to find better solution, but why the solution above is not working properly.

Comment: When you're using the wrong tool for the job, all sort of unexpected problems can occur...

Comment: Thats just you saing you dont know why it doesnt work... Im interested in reason why it doesnt work.

Comment: Out of curiosity what does you function return when the table is empty when you call it directly with your `@Name`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I do care, because your best guess is not how constraints are supposed to work (as far as I know).

Comment: @HoneyBadger how do you think they are supposed to work? a check constraint has access to values of the rows being inserted/updated/deleted - how would you implement such a thing without accessing the table's data, and how would you deny the insert/update/delete after the transaction is commited? Please remember that SQL Server use implicit transaction on every stand-alone DML statement.

Comment: Constraints (all types) logically execute after the DML statement has run but before it commits, in much the same way `AFTER` triggers do. It is almost always wrong to use a `CHECK` constraints that crosses rows, both because of this reason, but also because `CHECK` constraints should logically always hold (unlike triggers) and the engine does *not* re-evaluate the constraint for rows that are not affected by the statement, making it trivial to introduce inconsistencies that will bite you later (on a seemingly completely unrelated statement).

Comment: While I don't disagree with how sql server handles constraints (first insert, then check, then rollback the batch if the check fails [more info here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/handling-constraint-violations-and-errors-in-sql-server/)) I 100% disagree with *"I don't know and frankly, I don't really care much"*. The question is simple and the comments are flooded with people trying to play this off like an XY problem instead of answering the question even after OP has clearly stated they are aware of the XY angle and asked us to disregard.

Comment: @jnevill The reason I don't care is because this is clearly the wrong tool for the job. It's like attempting to use a hammer when what you really need as a screwdriver - I just think that if you know what the right tool is, using the wrong one is not a smart move.

Comment: I wonder why my previous comment got ereased.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constraint you added **to the table** actually means that you can't insert **any name** in the table, because for any value inserted in the table the function should return 1.
This is impossible because if the name was inserted then the constraint would be violated.
This is why `count(*) - 1` works: if there is already a name inserted and you tried to insert the same name **then** the constraint would be violated.

Comment: So it first inserts the row, then checks and rollbacks?

Comment: Something like that. The constraint is violated by any insert.

Comment: 'Something like that' Could you elaborate please? (the upvote and accept is yours)

Comment: When I say 'Something like that' I mean that of course **there is an attempt to insert**. Whether it is done and rolled back I can't be sure because I don't really know how the system works in deep at these cases. But the sure thing is that the transaction does not succeed because of the violation of the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

If you want unique names in a table, do not use a `check` constraint, use a `unique` constraint (or equivalently a unique index):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Names] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT unq_names_name UNIQUE (Name);
```

Comment: I am very surprised this would garner an anonymous downvote.  I would appreciate it if someone would explain why a unique constraint should be implemented using a check constraint.

Comment: I did not downvote but maybe this is the result of not answering the real question, as the OP says in a comment: *The point of the question is not to find better solution, but why the solution above is not working properly*

Comment: @forpas . . . This site should be about the correct way of implementing things.  If people want help with their homework, they should talk to their instructor.

Comment: This is not a case of *help for homework*. The OP has created something that does not work. So they need to know *why it does not work*. It is as simple as that.

Comment: @forpas - it does not work because it is the wrong way to solve the problem.  However, your answer was excellent in explaining what was happening.

Comment: @Hogan this question is not about *how to solve the problem*. It is about *why this code does not work as expected*.

Comment: I was the down voter. Apologies for not leaving a reason. @forpas explained my reasoning perfectly. In hindsight I'd remove my down vote if I could, since an answer detailing the correct approach is definitely beneficial.